# How to set text or add text to a specific line in multiline EditText in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to set text or add text to a **specific line in the EditText** in android? Are there any methods available?

As I know `setText` will overwrite the whole text and `append` will add text at the end, is there any specific method for what I want to do?

I know how to read and get a text from specific line, but how to make changes to that text without disturbing other lines below and above it?

Comment: you can better use **onLongClickListener()** to make changes on existing text with your  required condition.

Comment: What's with the downvote? Whats wrong with the question?

Comment: Store the old String in a temporary String and add new line character where you want  my modifying the string is one approach

Comment: actually i don't down vote it..i don't know down voters reason.may be your questing is poor logic based.

Comment: That's perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 2):

1) get the `Editable` from `EditText` using `EditText#getText();`

2) do your modifications to the `Editable` you've get in previous step.

`Editable` has a method `insert(int where, CharSequence text)` - use it to insert where you want.

3) set it back to the `EditText` using `EditText#setText();` (SET THE WHOLE MODIFIED `Editable` BACK)

If you want to know where there are end of line signs in the `Editable` you received then search it for the new line char aka '\n', then use this place/places to insert somethig after the `'\n'`, if you want to insert in a particular line that is alligned by EditText, then you need to get to the "alligning engine" of `EditText`, I dont't know the details how this works, so you need to read the sources if you want to do that.

Comment: How to set it back, thats the question. if I use setText it will overwrite whole editText, if I use append then it will be only added at the end, I am interested in knowing how to set or add text to specific line of multiline edittext

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki suggests to edit the text on the control, and set the entire content back after making the change.

Like if the EditText has the text 12456, you first pull the entire text on it, append 3 in between, and set 123456 back to the EditText. You are basically overwriting the entire text content

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki 's solution seems correct. Cant think of a reason for the downvote

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki dont know who down voted, I dont even have privilege to down vote, I will try as you say and will get back to you .

Comment: It looks like there are some SO users just hunting me down because they just  do not like me, but I'am here not by the reason to be liked, but because I like to help others.

Comment: Someone has downvoted my Question too, don't understand whats wrong with it.

Comment: My dear fellow users, I am the arrogant hater who downvoted the initial version of this answer. I apologize for not taking time to give explanations, therefore I will do it now. In my very humble opinion the answer was "not useful" (i.e downvotable) because it did not provide any information about how to insert some text at a specific line, which was, in my very humble opinion, the main focus of the question. The answer has been edited since then, and I removed the downvote because, in my very humble opinion, the missing information has been added. Kindly yours.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using this type code

```
EditText edt_Text= new EditText(this);
edt_Text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
edt_Text.setText("Hi how you");
lnrImageButton.addView(edt_Text);
```

and set button onClick to add new character which you want

```
menu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            edt_Text.getText().insert(6, "are");
        }
    });
```

this code is for specific character base

now you should find line from character and insert text using this method.

i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the multi line text will be separated by a line breaks and the below code will give you a clarification

```
public class EditTextExample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edtittext_example);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.m_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
    }


    //button listener
    private OnClickListener btnListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick (View view) {

    EditText etMultiLinetext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMultiLineText);
    String str = etMultiLinetext.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    TextView tvMultiLineText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMultiLineText);
    String[] strArr = str.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        Log.e("String value", "String value" + strArr[i]);
    }
    tvMultiLineText.setText(str);
   }
  }; 
}
```

And I f you wanna add the content in edit text you can add by getting the `EditText` value and append the string whatever you need and you can set it back like below

`etMultiLine.setText("Edited Text");`